How to Resolve HeuristicMixedException in Narayana after Stack Upgrade?
I've been working on a Java Spring-based application that manages transactions using Narayana.
The code base is very vast and we have been just told to upgrade the stack. None of my team members have expertise and much knowledge of the codebase. Recently, I upgraded our stack, which includes MySQL, JMS, and Narayana, among others. Following the upgrade, I'm encountering unexpected HeuristicMixedException errors during transaction commits. The same configurations worked without issues in the previous stack.
Upgraded Non-working Stack Versions:
•   Narayana: 5.10.6
•   MySQL Connector/J: 8.4.0
•   Spring: 5.3.x
•   Hibernate: 5.3.x
•   Java: Amazon Corretto JDK 11
Older working stack:
•   Narayana : 5.9.2
•   MySQL Connector/J: 5.1.44
•   Spring: 4.3.10
•   Hibernate: 4.2.1
•   Java: Amazon Corretto JDK 8
I'm unsure if the exception is due to configuration changes or something related to the upgrade.
Details of the Problem
After upgrading, I started seeing HeuristicMixedException errors in the logs. There are multiple things happen at this enterprise app on server start and few of those seems to be related to some XAconnection based DB queries and also some spring jms stuffs. What we observed is, the application setup includes:

MySQL Connection configured as an XA and NON-XA resource in Narayana.

JMS Connection configured as a non-XA resource, which I intend to keep as is since this has been a working code in the old stack.
Here’s a snippet of the stack trace from the logs:

2024-11-01 22:15:43,057 DEBUG
[org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager]
[Catalina-utility-1] []   Creating new transaction with name
[com.abcd.riskmanager.jpa.dao.ConfigDao.findAll]:
PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_DEFAULT 2024-11-01 22:15:43,057
DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils]
[Catalina-utility-1] []   Opening JPA EntityManager 2024-11-01
22:15:43,058 DEBUG
[com.abcd.Enterprise.spring.jta.cache.TransactionalContextResourceRegistryCache]
[Catalina-utility-1] []   Resource not available in cache for key:
DS20:ffff0aab40c5:a21c:67259939:4ac 2024-11-01 22:15:43,071 DEBUG
[com.abcd.Enterprise.spring.jta.cache.TransactionalContextResourceRegistryCache]
[Catalina-utility-1] []   Resource Cached resource wrapper over :
com.arjuna.ats.internal.jdbc.ConnectionImple@65b48420 cached for key
DS20:ffff0aab40c5:a21c:67259939:4ac 2024-11-01 22:15:43,075 WARN
[com.abcd.rearch.tcserver.jdbc.pool.ENTERPRISEConnectionPoolInterceptor]
[Catalina-utility-1] []   Active transaction < formatId=131077,
gtrid_length=31, bqual_length=36,
tx_uid=0:ffff0aab40c5:a21c:67259939:4ac, node_name=i91,
branch_uid=0:ffff0aab40c5:a21c:67259939:4af, subordinatenodename=null,
eis_name=0 > detected in connection,
PooledConnection[com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionWrapper@6f0f1e46].
Connection will be discarded 2024-11-01 22:15:43,085 DEBUG
[org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager]
[Catalina-utility-1] []   Initiating transaction commit 2024-11-01
22:15:43,097 WARN
[com.abcd.riskmanager.decision.component.config.ConfigurationManager]
[Catalina-utility-1] []   default in-memory configuration setup error,
using default configuration manager
org.springframework.transaction.HeuristicCompletionException:
Heuristic completion: outcome state is mixed; nested exception is
javax.transaction.HeuristicMixedException     at
org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1042)
at
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
at
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
at
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:637)
at
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:390)
at
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:134)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy146.findAll(Unknown Source)  at
com.abcd.riskmanager.decision.component.config.InMemoryConfigurationManager.(InMemoryConfigurationManager.java:45)
at
com.abcd.riskmanager.decision.component.config.TreeCacheConfigurationManager.(TreeCacheConfigurationManager.java:36)
at
com.abcd.riskmanager.decision.component.config.ConfigurationManager.getInstance(ConfigurationManager.java:164)
at
com.abcd.riskmanager.decision.strategy.TreeCacheStrategyCache.(TreeCacheStrategyCache.java:51)
at
com.abcd.riskmanager.decision.strategy.TranslatedStrategyCache.(TranslatedStrategyCache.java:28)
at
com.abcd.riskmanager.decision.component.workflow.WorkflowEngine.dbLookupStrategy(WorkflowEngine.java:674)
at
com.abcd.riskmanager.decision.component.workflow.PlugInManager.findPlugIns(PlugInManager.java:368)
at
com.abcd.riskmanager.decision.component.workflow.PlugInManager.init(PlugInManager.java:125)
at
com.abcd.riskmanager.decision.entry.StartupShutdownServlet.init(StartupShutdownServlet.java:57)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:143)   at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1106)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1063)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:960)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4641)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4948)
at
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:661)
at
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:680)
at
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1844)
at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) Caused by:
javax.transaction.HeuristicMixedException     at
com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1303)
at
com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126)
at
org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1035)
... 36 more     Suppressed: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXAException:
Undetermined error occurred in the underlying Connection - check your
data for consistency      at
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXAConnection.mapXAExceptionFromSQLException(MysqlXAConnection.java:337)
at
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXAConnection.dispatchCommand(MysqlXAConnection.java:319)
at
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXAConnection.commit(MysqlXAConnection.java:296)
at
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.SuspendableXAConnection.commit(SuspendableXAConnection.java:98)
at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
Method)       at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)       at
com.abcd.rearch.tcserver.jdbc.pool.ENTERPRISEDataSourceXAResourceHandler.invoke(ENTERPRISEDataSourceXAResourceHandler.java:63)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy197.commit(Unknown Source)       at
com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.XAResourceRecord.topLevelOnePhaseCommit(XAResourceRecord.java:702)
at
com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.onePhaseCommit(BasicAction.java:2395)
at
com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.End(BasicAction.java:1497)
at
com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:96)
at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162)
at
com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1295)
... 38 more     Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException:
No operations allowed after connection closed.        at
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:102)
at
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
at
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:81)
at
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:55)
at
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:65)
at
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
at
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:1103)
at
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:1094)
at
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXAConnection.dispatchCommand(MysqlXAConnection.java:311)
... 52 more     Caused by:
com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ConnectionIsClosedException: No operations
allowed after connection closed.      at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
Method)       at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
at
com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:52)
at
com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:95)
at
com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:140)
at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.checkClosed(NativeSession.java:915)
at
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:586)
at
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createStatement(ConnectionImpl.java)
...Configurations



Narayana Properties
Here are my current Narayana properties:


<properties>
>     <entry key="CoordinatorEnvironmentBean.defaultTimeout">9000</entry>
>     <entry key="CoordinatorEnvironmentBean.txReaperTimeout">120000</entry>
>     <entry key="CoordinatorEnvironmentBean.txReaperMode">DYNAMIC</entry>
>     <entry key="CoordinatorEnvironmentBean.commitOnePhase">YES</entry>
>     <entry key="ObjectStoreEnvironmentBean.localOSRoot">defaultStore</entry>
>     <entry key="ObjectStoreEnvironmentBean.objectStoreDir">${arjuna.objectstore}</entry>
>     <entry key="ObjectStoreEnvironmentBean.objectStoreSync">ON</entry>
>     <entry key="ObjectStoreEnvironmentBean.transactionSync">ON</entry>
>     <entry key="CoreEnvironmentBean.nodeIdentifier">i91</entry>
>     <entry key="JTAEnvironmentBean.allowMultipleLastResources">true</entry>
>     <entry key="narayana.transactionManager.enableHeuristicCommit">true</entry>
>     <entry key="narayana.transactionManager.enableHeuristicRollback">true</entry>
> </properties>

The key properties I added to potentially address the heuristic issue include without luck:

• JTAEnvironmentBean.allowMultipleLastResources: set to true to allow
a single non-XA resource as the "last resource" in XA transactions.
• narayana.transactionManager.enableHeuristicCommit and
narayana.transactionManager.enableHeuristicRollback: set to true to
handle cases where partial commits or rollbacks are required.

Spring JMS Listener Configuration
My JMS listener configuration in Spring is non-XA but runs in the same transaction context as my XA database operations:




EnterpriseDataSourceFactory Customization
I also have a custom EnterpriseDataSourceFactory class to handle XA connections. Below was the old implementation which caused below error:

org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.SQLException: Connection from pool does not implement javax.sql.XAConnection at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:82) at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:646)

So I had to change the implementations of this class to make it work in the new stack. Not sure why the error happened though and if it has anything to do with the current heuristic exception I am getting.
Old Implementation worked in old stack, failed in new stack:
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory;
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolConfiguration;

import com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource;

public class EnterpriseDataSourceFactory extends DataSourceFactory{
@Override
    public DataSource createDataSource(Properties properties,Context context, boolean XA) throws Exception {
        PoolConfiguration poolProperties = DataSourceFactory.parsePoolProperties(properties);
        if (poolProperties.getDataSourceJNDI()!=null && poolProperties.getDataSource()==null) {
            performJNDILookup(context, poolProperties);
        }
        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource dataSource = XA?
                new EnterpriseDataSource(poolProperties) :
                new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource(poolProperties);
        dataSource.createPool();
        return dataSource;
    }
}

New Implementation:
public class EnterpriseDataSourceFactory extends DataSourceFactory{
    @Override
public DataSource createDataSource(Properties properties, Context context, boolean XA) throws Exception {
        PoolConfiguration poolProperties = DataSourceFactory.parsePoolProperties(properties);
         // Perform JNDI lookup if required
        if (poolProperties.getDataSourceJNDI() != null && poolProperties.getDataSource() == null) {
            performJNDILookup(context, poolProperties);
        }

    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource dataSource;
    if (XA) {
        MysqlXADataSource mysqlXADataSource = new MysqlXADataSource();
        mysqlXADataSource.setUrl(poolProperties.getUrl());
        mysqlXADataSource.setUser(poolProperties.getUsername());
        mysqlXADataSource.setPassword(poolProperties.getPassword());
        dataSource = new EnterpriseDataSource(poolProperties);
        ((ENTERPRISEDataSource) dataSource).setDataSource(mysqlXADataSource);
        } else {
        dataSource = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource(poolProperties);
    }

    dataSource.createPool();
    return dataSource;
}}

Server.xml JNDI entries:
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
             UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
        <Resource name="UserDatabase" 
            auth="Container"
            description="User database that can be updated and saved"
            factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
            pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml"
        />
        <Resource name="jdbc/EnterpriseTracking"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
            username="${dbUserName}"
            password="${dbPassword}"
            url="${dbBaseUrl}${dbTrackingSchema}${dbProperties}"
            minIdle="5"
            initialSize="5"
            maxActive="100"
            maxWait="60000"
            validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            validationQueryTimeout="5"
            testOnBorrow="true"
            testOnReturn="true"
            validationInterval="10000"
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
            testWhileIdle="true"
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="900000"
            removeAbandoned="true"
            removeAbandonedTimeout="300"
        />
        <Resource name="jdbc/EnterpriseDecisionLocalDataSource"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
            username="${dbUserName}"
            password="${dbPassword}"
            url="${dbBaseUrl}${dbDecisionSchema}${dbProperties}"
            minIdle="5"
            initialSize="5"
            maxActive="100"
            maxWait="60000"
            validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            validationQueryTimeout="5"
            testOnBorrow="true"
            testOnReturn="true"
            validationInterval="10000"
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
            testWhileIdle="true"
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="900000"
            removeAbandoned="true"
            removeAbandonedTimeout="300"
        />
        <Resource name="jdbc/EnterpriseRMDecisionDataSource"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
            username="${dbUserName}"
            password="${dbPassword}"
            url="${dbBaseUrl}${dbDecisionSchema}${dbProperties}"
            minIdle="5"
            initialSize="5"
            maxActive="100"
            maxWait="60000"
            validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            validationQueryTimeout="5"
            testOnBorrow="true"
            testOnReturn="true"
            validationInterval="10000"
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
            testWhileIdle="true"
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="900000"
            removeAbandoned="true"
            removeAbandonedTimeout="300"
        />
        <Resource name="jdbc/EnterpriseTrackingLocalDataSource"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
            username="${dbUserName}"
            password="${dbPassword}"
            url="${dbBaseUrl}${dbTrackingSchema}${dbProperties}"
            minIdle="5"
            initialSize="5"
            maxActive="100"
            maxWait="60000"
            validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            validationQueryTimeout="5"
            testOnBorrow="true"
            testOnReturn="true"
            validationInterval="10000"
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
            testWhileIdle="true"
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="900000"
            removeAbandoned="true"
            removeAbandonedTimeout="300"
        />
        <Resource name="jdbc/EnterpriseTrackingGenericDS"
            auth="Container"
                        xaDataSourceClassName="com.cybersource.rearch.tcserver.jdbc.pool.EnterpriseDataSource"
                        type="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.naming.GenericNamingResourcesFactory"
            user="${dbUserName}"
            password="${dbPassword}"
            url="${dbBaseUrl}${dbTrackingSchema}${dbProperties}"
        />
        <Resource name="jdbc/EnterpriseDecisionGenericDS"
            auth="Container"
            type="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
            xaDataSourceClassName="com.cybersource.rearch.tcserver.jdbc.pool.EnterpriseDataSource"
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.naming.GenericNamingResourcesFactory"
            user="${dbUserName}"
            password="${dbPassword}"
            url="${dbBaseUrl}${dbDecisionSchema}${dbProperties}"
        />
        <Resource name="jdbc/EnterpriseHop.DataSource"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.XADataSource"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
            xaDataSourceClassName="com.cybersource.rearch.tcserver.jdbc.pool.EnterpriseDataSource"
            dataSourceJNDI="EnterpriseTrackingGenericDS"
            factory="com.cybersource.rearch.tcserver.jdbc.pool.EnterpriseDataSourceFactory"
            jdbcInterceptors="com.cybersource.rearch.tcserver.jdbc.pool.EnterpriseConnectionPoolInterceptor"
            minIdle="5"
            initialSize="5" 
            maxActive="100"
            maxWait="60000"
            validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            validationQueryTimeout="5"
            testOnBorrow="true"
            testOnReturn="true"
            validationInterval="10000"
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
            testWhileIdle="true"
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="900000"
            removeAbandoned="true"
            removeAbandonedTimeout="300"
            username="${dbUserName}"
            password="${dbPassword}"
            url="${dbBaseUrl}${dbTrackingSchema}${dbProperties}"
        />
        <Resource name="jdbc/EnterpriseEnterprise.DataSource"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.XADataSource"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
            xaDataSourceClassName="com.cybersource.rearch.tcserver.jdbc.pool.EnterpriseDataSource"
            dataSourceJNDI="EnterpriseTrackingGenericDS"
            factory="com.cybersource.rearch.tcserver.jdbc.pool.EnterpriseDataSourceFactory"
            jdbcInterceptors="com.cybersource.rearch.tcserver.jdbc.pool.EnterpriseConnectionPoolInterceptor"
            minIdle="5"
            initialSize="5"
            maxActive="100"
            maxWait="60000"
            validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            validationQueryTimeout="5"
            testOnBorrow="true"
            testOnReturn="true"
            validationInterval="10000"
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
            testWhileIdle="true"
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="900000"
            removeAbandoned="true"
            removeAbandonedTimeout="300"
            username="${dbUserName}"
            password="${dbPassword}"
            url="${dbBaseUrl}${dbTrackingSchema}${dbProperties}"
        />
        <Resource name="jdbc/EnterpriseEnterpriseDataSource"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.XADataSource"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
            xaDataSourceClassName="com.cybersource.rearch.tcserver.jdbc.pool.EnterpriseDataSource"
            dataSourceJNDI="EnterpriseTrackingGenericDS"
            factory="com.cybersource.rearch.tcserver.jdbc.pool.EnterpriseDataSourceFactory"
            jdbcInterceptors="com.cybersource.rearch.tcserver.jdbc.pool.EnterpriseConnectionPoolInterceptor"
            minIdle="5"
            initialSize="5"
            maxActive="100"
            maxWait="60000"
            validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            validationQueryTimeout="5"
            testOnBorrow="true"
            testOnReturn="true"
            validationInterval="10000"
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
            testWhileIdle="true"
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="900000"
            removeAbandoned="true"
            removeAbandonedTimeout="300"
            username="${dbUserName}"
            password="${dbPassword}"
            url="${dbBaseUrl}${dbTrackingSchema}${dbProperties}"
        />
        <Resource name="jdbc/EnterpriseDecisionDataSource"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.XADataSource"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
            xaDataSourceClassName="com.cybersource.rearch.tcserver.jdbc.pool.EnterpriseDataSource"
            dataSourceJNDI="EnterpriseDecisionGenericDS"
            factory="com.cybersource.rearch.tcserver.jdbc.pool.EnterpriseDataSourceFactory"
            jdbcInterceptors="com.cybersource.rearch.tcserver.jdbc.pool.EnterpriseConnectionPoolInterceptor"
            minIdle="5"
            initialSize="5"
            maxActive="100"
            maxWait="60000"
            validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            validationQueryTimeout="5"
            testOnBorrow="true"
            testOnReturn="true"
            validationInterval="10000"
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
            testWhileIdle="true"
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="900000"
            removeAbandoned="true"
            removeAbandonedTimeout="300"
            username="${dbUserName}"
            password="${dbPassword}"
            url="${dbBaseUrl}${dbDecisionSchema}${dbProperties}"
        />
</GlobalNamingResources>

Custom Datasource implementation
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool;
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolConfiguration;
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.XADataSource;

/**
 * Creates a {@link EnterpriseConnectionPool} instance
 **/
public class EnterpriseDataSource extends XADataSource {

    public EnterpriseDataSource(PoolConfiguration poolProperties) {
        super(poolProperties);
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the connection pool, by creating a pooling driver.
     * 
     * @return Driver
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public ConnectionPool createPool() throws SQLException {
        if (pool != null) {
            return pool;
        } else {
            return pCreatePool();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the connection pool, by creating a pooling driver.
     * 
     * @return Driver
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    private synchronized ConnectionPool pCreatePool() throws SQLException {
        if (pool != null) {
            return pool;
        } else {
            pool = new EnterpriseConnectionPool(poolProperties);
            return pool;
        }
    }

}

The code being so vast and me not being sure where to pin point exactly, I am not sure if I have provided all the necessary snippets for some guidance. If needed I can surely provide more detail.
Questions

What could be causing the HeuristicMixedException after the upgrade, and is there a known compatibility issue with Narayana's latest version, spring 5.3, hibernate 5.3 and MySQL Connector/J 8.4.0?
Are the allowMultipleLastResources setting and enabling heuristic commit/rollback sufficient for Narayana to manage transactions, or are there additional configurations I need to consider?
How can I resolve the XA connection exception in EnterpriseDataSourceFactory with the latest MySQL Connector/J?
I am not sure but some research suggests that the heuristic mixed exception might be due to mixing NON XA and XA transactions. Which I am not sure is my case or not.
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!


I didn't study your report in detail but what I do notice is that you have enabled JTAEnvironmentBean.allowMultipleLastResources which is transactionally unsafe and should only be used during development, if at all. The last release did improve error reporting when this property is enabled and one of the one-phase aware resources did not commit - previously the reporting was a bit loose because we did not anticipate it being used on production code and I suspect that this is why you are seeing it now.
My recommendation is to only use XA-aware resources but, if you really must, then using a single one-phase aware resource gives you a better chance of getting safe transactional outcomes, still not guaranteed but significantly safer than using two one-phase resources.
The situation cannot be recovered because one-phase resources do not lock their data during the commit phase and they do not record what they did in the resource logs - on the other hand two phase resources do record what they did and lock data so the situation is recoverable.

Thanks Michael for your response. After enabling the trace log I found that the connection was getting closed just before narayana was trying to do a commit on it. Not sure why it was happening even after increasing the connection timeout and pool size. So I put a check in the connection pool interceptor to not close the connection if there are any active transactions associated with it. That seems to have solved the problem.
